# How can i get rows from database

Tags: sql

In my database there are fields where values like this:

```
14,20,12,13,1,22,28,23,5,3,30,15
```

I want to take that have a value `20`.

I tried to do like this:

```
SELECT * FROM USER WHERE 20 IN (expertise)
```

so but  returns  those lines which begin with 20

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM USER WHERE expertise=20
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM USER WHERE expertise IN (20)
```

OR If you have comma seperated values

```
 SELECT * FROM USER WHERE expertise like "%20%"
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT * FROM USER WHERE FIND_IN_SET(20,lawyer_expertise);